# Apache2, redirect to homepage when you visit folder with exact name

Tags: redirect, apache2

**Issue**

In apache, how can I redirect to homepage in case if you will go to exact string, but everything behind this string should be displayed normally, no redirect.

Example.

```
http://example.com/STRING -> go to homepage
http://example.com/STRING_PAGE -> go to http://example.com/STRING_PAGE
```

**I tried**

```
Redirect 301 /STRING http://example.com/
```

But in this case page is redirected to homepage too, for example in case of `http://example.com/STRING_PAGE`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mod_alias` and its [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive,
you can use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) using a `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/STRING_PAGE [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?STRING       / [R=301,NC,L]
```

This redirects all requests starting with `/STRING` or `STRING`, but not starting with `/STRING_PAGE`. 
The match for a leading slash `^/` is needed if the rule is defined in a `VirtualHost` context and must be omitted in a `<Directory/>` or `.htaccess` context. It's just easier to use `/?` to make it optional, so the rule can be used in both.

The [NC](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) flag is used for a case-insensitive match and [L](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) stops 
processing any following rules.

You need to enable `mod_rewrite` (`sudo a2enmod rewrite`) to use this.

Comment: Thanks, yes, at the end, I used `Rewrite`.

Comment: Although this doesn't match the "exact name", it matches _everything_ that starts `/STRING` _except_ `/STRING_PAGE`. It would still redirect `/STRING_ANOTHERPAGE`, etc.

Comment: @MrWhite Correct and I overlooked the "exact string" in the question. For an exact match `RewriteRule ^/?STRING$ / [R=301,NC,L]` should be sufficient (without `RewriteCond`).